# Inner Product equaling 0 and elements being equal to 0

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, analysis, hilbert-spaces, inner-products

I have the following inner product: $\langle u(x), uu^{*}u(x)-u(x)\rangle = 0$ for all $x$, and the textbook I'm reading says this implies $uu^{*}u=u$.  Why is this true?  This to me only says that $u(x)$ is orthogonal to $uu^{*}u(x)-u(x)$ for all $x$ or more generally that $uu^{*}u(x)-u(x) \in \text{Ran}(u)^{\perp} = \text{ker}(u^{*})$.

I know in general if you have $\langle f,g \rangle = 0$, you don't get to automatically conclude that $f$ or $g=0$ since the inner product isn't injective.  I do know however that if $\langle f,g \rangle = 0$ for all $g$, then we can conclude that $f=0$ by setting $g=f$.

However, the inner product $\langle u(x), uu^{*}u(x)-u(x)\rangle = 0$ doesn't have this form, since it's equal to $0$ for all $x$, and on top of that, the left slot depends on $x$ as well.

For context $u:X \longrightarrow X$ is a bounded linear map.

Any help on understanding this would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: I find your argument that $uu^*u(x) - u(x) \in \operatorname{Ran}(u)^\perp$ to be suspect. You can only conclude is perpendicular to $u(x)$ for the particular $x$, not for all $x$. If you change $x$, then $uu^*u(x) - u(x)$ could change with it. If you could fix up that part of the proof, then you'd be done, as it's much easier to note that $u(u^*u(x) - x) \in \operatorname{Ran}(u)$.

Comment: @TheoBendit, sorry I forgot to mention that  $u^{*}u$ is a projection, so $u^{*}(uu^{*}u(x)-u(x))= (u^{*}u)^2(x)-(u^{*}u)(x)=0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking transposes, $$\langle u^*ux,u^*ux-x\rangle=0$$  Let $A=u^*u$; then $$x^*A(A-1)x=0\tag{1}$$  $A$ is clearly self-adjoint; by taking transposes of scalars, for any $x,y$, we have $$(x+y)^*A(A-1)(x+y)=0+2x^*A(A-1)y+0=2x^*A(A-1)y$$  Since $x$ and $y$ were arbitrary, $$A(A-1)=0$$ i.e. $A$ is a projection onto its range.

Now note that $x\in\ker{(A)}$ iff $x\in\ker{(u)}$.  So if $Ax=0$, then $ux=0=uAx$; otherwise, $Ax=1$, and $uAx=ux$.